# Generate `LocalTime` from OpenAPI specification

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I see that there is a `date` format for strings in OpenAPI, and that by using `dateLibrary=java8` we can generate `LocalDate` fields by using `openapi-generator`.

But is there any way of producing `LocalTime` fields? There is no `time` format in OpenAPI and the `date-time` one produces `OffsetDateTime`.

EDIT: It's hard offering a reproducible example since the question is about something I can't do, but some illustrative example would be that I want something along the lines of:

A schema specification:

```yaml
Visit:
  type: object
  parameters:
    visitor:
      type: string
    timeOfVisit:
      type: string
      format: time
```

But obviously the `time` format is not present in the OpenAPI specification. The generated code should be something like

```java
public class Visit {
  private String visitor;
  private LocalTime timeOfVisit;

  // Getters, setters, etc
}
```

There must surely be some way for `openapi-generator` to produce this output, isn't it? I've found that there are some `import-mappings` that map `LocalTime` to `org.joda.time.*` so there seems to be a way of having it produce `LocalTime` types, but I haven't found it

Comment: You can use the `OffsetDateTime` and call `myOffsetDateTime.toLocalTime()`.

Comment: It could work but it's not too effective, firstly, I'd have to do that in a lot of different places, and also, setting the parameter as `date-time` in the OpenAPI specification would communicate that it allows any combination of date and time, while it actually only works with time. I guess my wording wasn't very good, because what I'd like is to have a time parameter in my API and also in the generated code. (Maybe using a regex pattern for the string is my only choice?)

Comment: Sorry, I think it was not the wording but the lack of example values and code. Could you provide some minimal and reproducible example of the situation?

Comment: I've added a small example of what I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it! Actually it was really easy, but being a beginner in OpenAPI it was hard finding a solution.Given the example in my question, I'd just have to run `openapi-generator-cli` as

`openapi-generator-cli generate -g java --type-mappings time=LocalTime`

And *voilà*, it's done!

EDIT:
But this doesn't use `java.time.LocalTime` as a type because of the previously (in the question) mentioned `import-mappings`, so the definitive command would be:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -g java --type-mappings time=LocalTime --import-mappings LocalTime=java.time.LocalTime
```

EDIT:

An alternative is to configure the plugin inside your pom.xml:

```xml
<configuration>
    <typeMappings>
        <typeMapping>time=LocalTime</typeMapping>
    </typeMappings>
    <importMappings>
        <importMapping>LocalTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</importMapping>
    </importMappings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: OK, good... Because [the specifiation](https://swagger.io/specification/) includes only the two types you already mentioned: `date-time` and `date`…

Comment: Is there a way to use the same thing using the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`

Comment: Yeah, use the following snippet inside your `<configuration>...</configuration>` block in your `pom.xml`:  
```java
<typeMappings>
   <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</typeMapping>
</typeMappings>
<importMappings>  
<importMapping>java.time.OffsetDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</importMapping>
 </importMappings>
```
  
Sorry for the poor formatting. You might have to fully qualify `OffsetDateTime` in `typeMapping` too, but this worked for me

Comment: @Haf: Can you please remove the snippet from your comment, it is not equivalent to the solution you provide in your answer ? I sent you an edit to your answer, to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that there is a dateLibrary option in the configOptions tag in the pom.xml. This way I didn't have to map manually between OffsetDateTime (which was being generated at first) and LocalDateTime.

If you add true to the configuration tag it will print out all the options.

```
dateLibrary
        Option. Date library to use (Default: threetenbp)
            joda - Joda (for legacy app only)
            legacy - Legacy java.util.Date (if you really have a good reason not to use threetenbp
            java8-localdatetime - Java 8 using LocalDateTime (for legacy app only)
            java8 - Java 8 native JSR310 (preferred for jdk 1.8+) - note: this also sets "java8" to true
            threetenbp - Backport of JSR310 (preferred for jdk < 1.8)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring with gradle you need to add this two properties to build.gradle

```
openApiGenerate() {
    generatorName = "spring"
    ...
    typeMappings = ["time": "LocalTime"]
    importMappings = ["LocalTime": "java.time.LocalTime"]
}
```

So this configuration will say that `format: time` will generate `LocalTime` type and `java.time.LocalTime` here is the source of this type.